# Using Warbler, how do I exclude Active Record from the bundled gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

When using Warbler, what line(s) do I need to add to `config/warble.rb` to keep it from including Active Record in the bundled gems. I already have excluded Active Record in `config/environment.rb` as shown below.

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]
```

I tried the same thing only using `config.gems` in `config/warble.rb`, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you worked out the answer yet? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to try either of these ideas, but looking at [Nick Sieger's examples](http://github.com/nicksieger/jruby-rack/) :-

- Does the gem name have to be a String rather than a Symbol?
- It looks like `activerecord` maybe being included implicitly because `config.gems` includes `rails` and `config.gem_dependencies = true`. Maybe you need to change `config.gem_dependencies` to `false` and explicitly include `rails`, `actioncontroller`, etc in `config.gems`.

It might be instructive to print out or log the value of `config.gems` from within the `warble.rb` file.